# Как работать со связями многие-ко-многим, используя LINQ?

Tags: c#, sql, winforms, entity-framework, linq

Как работать со связями многие-ко-многим?

Я реализовал программу для работы с БД, использовал *Entity Framework*, т.е. создал классы модели и т.д.

При разработке ПО выяснилось что две таблицы из БД должны иметь связь многие ко многим.  Когда база была создана (подход *Codе First*) в базе между двумя таблицами появилась ещё одна. Всё в принципе хорошо программа работает, но вот из-за того что появилась эта таблица я не могу работать программно с ней т.к. я не создавал класса(модель) этой таблицы в итоге когда у меня есть какой нибудь `Id` первой таблице по которому мне нужно получить что нибудь из второй через *LINQ* я этого сделать не могу, приходится писать запрос "вручную". Как можно решить данную проблему, что бы можно было программно работать со связями многие ко многим через *LINQ*?

```
ServiceStationContext  db = new ServiceStationContext();
public class WorkOrder1
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Accepter { get; set; }
    public string Foreman { get; set; }
    public string myDate { get; set; }    
    public ICollection<GuideWorkTypeStandardHour1> GuideWorkTypeStandardHour1s { get; set; }
    public WorkOrder1()
    {
       GuideWorkTypeStandardHour1s = new List<GuideWorkTypeStandardHour1>();             
    }
}


public class GuideWorkTypeStandardHour1
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string CodeWork { get; set; }
    public ICollection<WorkOrder1> WorkOrder1s { get; set; }
    public GuideWorkTypeStandardHour1()
    {
        WorkOrder1s = new List<WorkOrder1>();
    }

}
```

Сохранение в БД:

```
private void button1_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    WorkOrder1 wo = new WorkOrder1();
    wo.myDate = maskedTextBoxData.Text;
    wo.Accepter = textBoxAccepter.Text;
    wo.Foreman = textBoxForeman.Text;
    wo.BestPractice = textBox4Recommendation.Text;

    db.WorkOrders.Add(wo);
    db.SaveChanges();
}
```

Считывание из БД с учётом подсказки указанной ниже(т.е. св-ва теперь `virtual`)

```
List<GuideWorkTypeStandardHour1> guideWorkTypeStandardHour1;
WorkOrder1 workOrder1 = db.WorkOrders.Find(ListWorkOrders.workorderselectedId);

var works = db.GuideWorkTypeStandardHour1s;

foreach(var w in works)
{
    if(workOrder1.GuideWorkTypeStandardHour1s.Contains(w))
    {
        guideWorkTypeStandardHour1.Add(w);
    }   
}
```

Comment: Что Вы понимаете под писать запрос в ручную? И покажите классы

Comment: Т.е. просто используя язык запросов SQL

Comment: Приведите классы которые Вы создали и код как Вы пишет запросы

Comment: Классы модели выложил. Попробуйте по известному Id какого нибудь заказа найти соответствующие работы в таблице

Comment: навигационные свойства у Вас есть, что Вы видите когда обращаетесь к ним, null? мне не совсем понятно по какому полю у Вас связь?

Comment: если правильно я вас понял, то да в навигационном свойстве null

Comment: Что имеем: Ссылка на объект класса   `WorkOrder1 workOrder1 = db.WorkOrders.Find(ListWorkOrders.workorderselectedId);` которую получаем по Id

Comment: уберите лишние поля что бы сократить модели, оставьте только необходимые для данного примера.

Comment: lazy loading поддерживается вообще в winforms??

Comment: `lazy loading` никакого отношения к winforms отношения не имеет.  Вы видели пример который я Вам привел, Вы можете создать консольное приложение и вставить его внутрь класс Program и все будет работать.

Answer (score 9):

Писать длинные имена классов мне лень - поэтому я поясню работу с MtM-связами на примере вот такой простой модели:

```
public class A {
  public int Id { get; set; }
  public virtual ICollection<B> Bs { get; set; }
}

public class B {
  public int Id { get; set; }
  public virtual ICollection<A> As { get; set; }
}
```

### 1. Сохранение связи в базу

1.1 Создание связи между уже привязанными к контексту сущностями

```
public void Connect(A a, B b) {
    if (a.Bs == null) // Проверка на случай отсутствия Lazy Loading
      a.Bs = new List<B>();

    a.Bs.Add(b);

    // И не забыть SaveChanges()
}
```

1.2 Создание связи по Id

```
public void Connect(DbContext ctx, int ida, int idb) {
    var a = new A { Id = ida };
    var b = new B { Id = idb };

    // Если сущности c указанными ключами уже загружены в контекст - тут будет ошибка
    // Постарайтесь, чтобы так не случалось (лучший способ - каждый раз создавать новый контекст)
    ctx.Entry(a).State = EntityState.Unchanged;
    ctx.Entry(b).State = EntityState.Unchanged;
    a.Bs = new List<B> { b }; // Если тут использовать массив - полезут ошибки при отслеживании связей в будущем. Но если контекст - временный, то можно и массив использовать.
    ctx.SaveChanges();

    // Очистка контекста - можно не делать, если контекст больше не будет использоваться
    ctx.Entry(a).State = EntityState.Detached;
    ctx.Entry(b).State = EntityState.Detached;
}
```

### 2. Удаление связи между сущностями

2.1 Сущности уже загружены в контекст

```
public void Disconnect(A a, B b) {
    a.Bs.Remove(b); // Тут не может быть NPE если обе записи загружены в контекст.

    // И не забыть SaveChanges()
}
```

2.2 Сущностей в контексте еще нет

```
public void Disconnect(DbContext ctx, int ida, int idb) {
    var a = new A { Id = ida };
    var b = new B { Id = idb };
    a.Bs = new List<B> { b };

    // Если сущности c указанными ключами уже загружены в контекст - тут будет ошибка
    // Постарайтесь, чтобы так не случалось (лучший способ - каждый раз создавать новый контекст)
    ctx.Entry(a).State = EntityState.Unchanged;
    ctx.Entry(b).State = EntityState.Unchanged;

    a.Bs.Remove(b);
    ctx.SaveChanges();

    // Очистка контекста - можно не делать, если контекст больше не будет использоваться
    ctx.Entry(a).State = EntityState.Detached;
    ctx.Entry(b).State = EntityState.Detached;
}
```

### 3. Загрузка связей из БД

3.1 Lazy Loading включен

```
a.Bs // оно само загрузится
```

3.2 Ручная загрузка

```
ctx.Entry(a).Collection(_ => _.Bs).Load()
a.Bs // теперь загружено
```

3.3 Включение в запрос

```
var q = (from a in ctx.As
         where a.Id = 5
         select a).Include(a => a.Bs)
```

3.4 Получение связей по Id

```
var a = new A { Id = ida };
ctx.Entry(a).State = EntityState.Unchanged;
ctx.Entry(a).Collection(_ => _.Bs).Load();
//теперь a.Bs не пусто
```

---

Я привел примеры работы со связями. Но не рассматривайте их как готовые подпрограммы - число реальных ситуаций намного больше рассмотренных тут (к примеру, одна сущность может быть уже в контексте - а вторая задана своим Id).

Это именно примеры.

---

Отдельно замечу: почти любая операция над таблицей связей, кроме добавления новой связи, требует полной загрузки всех связанных записей. Если такое поведение нежелательно - надо создавать отдельную связную сущность, преобразовав MtM-отношение в два 1tM.

Примерно так:

```
public class A {
  public int Id { get; set; }
  public virtual ICollection<ABLink> ABLinks { get; set; }
}

public class B {
  public int Id { get; set; }
  public virtual ICollection<ABLink> ABLinks { get; set; }
}

public class ABLink {
  [Key]
  public int AId { get; set; }
  [ForeignKey("AId")]
  public virtual A A { get; set; }      

  [Key]
  public int BId { get; set; }
  [ForeignKey("BId")]
  public virtual B B { get; set; }      
}
```

В таком варианте запросы к БД несколько усложняются - зато можно удалять связи зная только Id концов, без операций загрузки данных из БД вообще.

Еще можно реализовать в сущности-связи интерфейс `IEntityWithChangeTracker`, чтобы иметь доступ из нее до контекста БД, чтобы можно было удалять ее зная только ссылку на нее саму, после чего реализовать коллекцию-проекцию, преобразующую `ICollection<ABLink>` в `ICollection<B>` - но это уже высший пилотаж.

Answer (score 5):

```
public class WorkOrder1
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Accepter { get; set; }
    public string Foreman { get; set; }
    public string myDate { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<GuideWorkTypeStandardHour1> GuideWorkTypeStandardHour1s { get; set; }
    public WorkOrder1()
    {
       GuideWorkTypeStandardHour1s = new List<GuideWorkTypeStandardHour1>();             
    }
}

public class GuideWorkTypeStandardHour1
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string CodeWork { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<WorkOrder1> WorkOrder1s { get; set; }
    public GuideWorkTypeStandardHour1()
    {
        WorkOrder1s = new List<WorkOrder1>();
    }
}
```

что бы получить связанные данные необходимо либо воспользоваться `lazy loading` для этого необходимо навигационное свойство переделать следующим образом

```
public virtual ICollection<GuideWorkTypeStandardHour1> GuideWorkTypeStandardHour1s { get; set; }
```

тогда при обращении к навигационному свойству EF подгрузит необходимые данные (аналогичным образом во втором классе), либо необходимо это сделать следующим образом:

```
var order =  db.WorkOrder
    .Where(x=>x.Id==512)
    .Include(x=>x.GuideWorkTypeStandardHour1s);
```

т.е. подгрузить явно

вот смотрите пример только с немного другими моделями:

```
public class Team
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Player> Players { get; set; }
    public Team()
    {
        Players = new List<Player>();
    }
}

public class Player
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }
    public string Position { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Team> Teams { get; set; }
    public Player()
    {
        Teams = new List<Team>();
    }
}

public class DefaultContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<ConsoleApplication2.Program.Player> Players { get; set; }
    public DbSet<ConsoleApplication2.Program.Team> Teams { get; set; }
}

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var db = new DefaultContext();
    Player pl1 = new Player { Name = "Роналду", Age = 31, Position = "Нападающий" };
    Player pl2 = new Player { Name = "Месси", Age = 28, Position = "Нападающий" };
    Player pl3 = new Player { Name = "Хави", Age = 34, Position = "Полузащитник" };
    Team t1 = new Team { Name = "Барселона" };
    t1.Players.Add(pl2);
    t1.Players.Add(pl3);
    Team t2 = new Team { Name = "Реал Мадрид" };
    t2.Players.Add(pl1);
    List<Team> teams = new List<Team>(){ t1,t2 };
    db.Teams.AddRange(teams);
    db.SaveChanges();

    var playerInTeam1 = db.Teams.First();
}
```

пример взят [здесь](http://metanit.com/sharp/entityframework/3.8.php)

Comment: второй вариант не работает 'Cannot convert lambda expression to type string because it is not a delegate type'. В чём отличие первого варианта от моего примера не вижу. Т.е. то что это не коллекция а просто свойство ? в коде у вас также всё.

Comment: @Vladimir у Вас навигационные поля **public ICollecion<>** у меня **public *virtual* ICollection<>** обновил ответ, попробуйте

Comment: Спасибо. Навигационное свойство появилось     `var reportQuery4 = workOrder1.GuideWorkTypeStandardHour1s.ToList();`,   но там **Count=0**. Что то сохраняю не так?

Comment: @Vladimir обновите свой вопрос: приведите пример как Вы записываете данные в бд, как считываете. кстати обновил ответ

Comment: В БД в таблице осуществляющей связь, записи есть!!!   Таблица с двумя столбцами в столбцы записываются данные: `workorder_Id`,  `GuideWorkTypeStandardHour1_Id`

Comment: [ForeignKey("Id")] это явное указание ключа для связи с другой таблицей.

Comment: Добавил [ForeignKey("Id")] - не помогло

Comment: Если посмотреть пример выше c всем известного  сайта "Метанин", то там всё  ОК  `t2.Players.Add(pl1);` и Count =2; У меня тоже при добавлении в одной форме  `wo.GuideWorkTypeStandardHour1s.Add(guideWorkTypeStandardHour1); ` Count   не равен 0. Но вот при последующем вызове на другой форме для какого нибудь `var work = WorkOrder.GuideWorkTypeStandardHour1s` здесь Count=0

Comment: @Vladimir Так у вас, получается, не с MtM проблема, а с устаревшими данными в контексте!

Comment: В смысле? не понял. Объясните пожалуйста!!!!!!!

Comment: @Vladimir приведите в вопросе пример как Вы создаете контекст для работы с БД(db) и в дальнейшем его используете

Answer (score 1):

Из за какой то ошибки не могу опубликовать ответ от себя (баллы обнулились).
Всем спасибо! Ответ на свой вопрос нашёл благодаря подсказке @Pavel Mayorov:

> @Vladimir Так у вас, получается, не с MtM проблема, а с устаревшими данными в контексте!

Вот решение моей проблемы! код который требовался:

```
db.Entry(workOrder1).Collection(p => p.GuideWorkTypeStandardHour1s).Load();
```