# Как удалить данные из коллекции при связи Многие ко многим

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

Есть 2 модели. Между ними связь многие ко многим.

```
public class Spares
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string SparePartName { get; set; }
        public double Price { get; set; }
        public int Count { get; set; }
        public string WinCode { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<Orders> Orders { get; set; }

        public Spares()
        {
            Orders = new List<Orders>();
        }
    }

public class Orders
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public DateTime OrderDate { get; set; }
        public string Status { get; set; }
        public double TotalPrice { get; set; }

        public int ClientsId { get; set; }
        public virtual Clients Clients { get; set; }

        public int? WorkingId { get; set; }
        public virtual Working Working { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<Spares> Spares { get; set; }

        public Orders()
        {
            Spares = new List<Spares>();
        }
    }
```

Как мне в Order'е удалить из коллекции spares конкретный spares по айдишнику который у меня есть? То есть я в своей программе привязываю в Orders.Spares какие то spares. А теперь мне нужно из коллекции spares 1 удалить.

Comment: Приаттачить и удалить?

Comment: А давайте мы вас задубликатим на хороший [ответ](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/456447/213987) Майорова? )